# Гебернация в другом HDD

Tags: windows, hdd

Если сделать полную копию жесткого диска на другой жесткий диск.
И этот другой жесткий диск вставить в компьютер. Дальше включить компьютер.

Суть в том, чтобы произошла при старте системы появилось "Восстановление Windows"
и после окончательной загрузке Windows. Появился мой открытый тестовой документ.

Такое возможно?

Comment: да, можно. Засунуть текстовый документ в автостарт.

Answer (score 0):

Если при старте появилось "Восстановление Windows" то гибернация уже не сможет отработать потому что это копия оперативной памяти, а восстановление эту память уже изменило

Comment: Ведь всё записывается в файл - hiberfil.sys (копия оперативной память), а если второй раз вызвать эту загрузку т.е. как-то запустить ещё раз. Не получиться второй раз?

Comment: возможен ли вообще запуск гибернации второй раз и последущие (копии типо). или это всё пустое и бесполезная трата времени?

Comment: на том же самом железе я думаю есть шансы, но при переносе на другое запустится опять восстановление и гибернацию отбросит

Comment: ок, возможен ли запуск гибернации второй раз?
Файл - hiberfil.sys на месте.

Т.е. включаю компьютер "Восстановление Windows"
загружается до конца Windows. как это можно сделать?

Comment: т.е. как можно запустить гибернацию второй раз

Comment: как можно запустить гибернацию второй раз? т.е. файл на месте.